# Как менять предыдущее сообщение от бота в чате после нажатия юзера на инлайн кнопку

Tags: python, aiogram

Имеется тг бот на python aiogram
Не могу понять как реализовать данную функцию идеи падают на `bot.edit_message_text()` и `call.message.edit_text` но пока я не понимаю как это реализовать на данном примере

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='start')

    async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
        buttons = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='1) Время работать!', callback_data='1) Время работать!'),
                   types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="2) Я не знаю что делать!", callback_data="3) Я не знаю что делать!"),
                   ]
        # first_name = callback.first_name  # Не может быть пустым
        await bot.edit_message_text(text="text")
        username = message.from_user.username
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        await message.answer(
            f"Охае, чайный мастер {message.from_user.first_name} \nМы уже знакомы - выбери первый пункт \nЕсли что-то пошло не так, то второй!",
            reply_markup=keyboard
        )
        await message.answer()
    
    
    # Знакомвство
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text='Знакомвство')
    async def meeting(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        buttons = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Написать ему в телеграмме', url=''),,
                   types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='start')
                   ]
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        await callback.message.answer(
            'Я телеграмм бот написанный для облегчения твоей работы ',
            reply_markup=keyboard)
        await callback.answer()

    @dp.callback_query_handler(text='1) Время работать!')
    async def time_to_work(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        buttons = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Чайная История на Пушке', callback_data='Чайная История на Пушке'),
                   types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Центральная Чайная История',
                                              callback_data='Центральная чайная история'),
                   ]
        await word_mentor()
        # print(send_mess.a_send_message)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        await callback.message.answer("Цитата дня:\n")
        # b = run(random.choice(lines))
        await callback.message.answer(random.choice(Words))
        # await callback.message.answer(b)
        await callback.message.answer("На какой точке ты сегодня работаешь?", reply_markup=keyboard)
        await callback.answer()
```

Отошлите пожалуйста пример с учтом данной информацией чтобы я мог допереть ибо в документации черт ногу сломит
Мне надо менять отправленное юзеру сообщение в зависимости от ого какую инлайн кнопку он нажмет

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить уже отправленное сообщение можно попробовать так:

```
current_mes = await callback.message.answer("Цитата дня:\n")
current_mes.edit_message(text='text')
```

Comment: А это будет работать если это сообщение в другом хендлере?

Answer (score 1):

В чем проблема юзать так:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def func1(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.edit_text(...)
```

В данном случае меняется сообщение к которому была привязана кнопка.

Comment: Меняется сообщение  из предыдущего хендлера?
Как при таком изменнении поменять кнопку?

Comment: Меняется сообщение к которому привязана кнопка

Comment: А как при этому варианте менять сами кнопки?
Сначала менять предложение а потом менять кнопки?

Comment: await call.message.edit_text(text="text", reply_markup=...)